# Selenium NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying the below code for web automation using python:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

web = webdriver.Chrome()
base_url = ""
web.get(base_url)
time.sleep(2)
team = web.find_element_by_xpath('// * [@id = "ReportViewerControl_xyz123_xyz456_dvalue"]/option[4]')
team.click()
```

However, I receive the following exception:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Comment: We need HTML to guide you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know some HTML first before starting to use `Selenium`. You get `NoSuchElementException` because the element was not found. You can  catch this error by using this import:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

and then writing a `try`/`except` block like this:

```
try:
  # your code
except NoSuchElementException:
  # this block of code will execute when you get this exception
```